# Como contar arquivos .xls / .xlsx na pasta com C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, diretório

Eu tenho uma *FolderBrowserDialog* e quando eu seleciono a pasta ele mostra a quantidade arquivos (todos, sem filtro). Como eu faço esse *length* somente com os arquivos de Excel (.xls, .xlsx).

Segue abaixo o código:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Arquivos na Pasta: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Alerta");
```

Comment: Congsegui parcialmente ! No array eu coloquei o seguinte comando. 
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.xlsx");
Ele ta verificando somente os arquivos xlsx, preciso que ele verifique também o xls.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Pronto no .NET de forma mais simples, que pode ser feito para ambas extensões é isto:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.xls");
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Arquivos na Pasta: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Alerta");
```

O ideal seria especificar as duas extensões individualmente mas não há nada pronto no .NET. Do jeito que está qualquer coisa que comece com "xls" e tenha mais um caractere qualquer será considerado, então pode haver um efeito colateral indesejado, por exemplo pegar os arquivos "xlsh" que eventualmente você tenha, é improvável mas pode acontecer.

Uma opção melhor para .NET 4.5:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                         .Where(file => file.ToLower().EndsWith("xls") ||
                                        file.ToLower().EndsWith("xlsx"))
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Arquivos na Pasta: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Alerta");
```

Retirado da [resposta do jgauffin no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039644/221800).

Se não puder usar o .NET 4.5 basta trocar o método `EnumerateFiles()` por `GetFiles()`, a única desvantagem é a performance já que o segundo não usa *lazy evaluation*.

Ainda achei esta opção:

[Multiple Filters On Directory.GetFiles Method](https://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Multiple-Filters-Directory.GetFiles-Method.aspx)

Simplificando o exemplo e adaptando para seu caso:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.xls");
files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.xlsx"));
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Arquivos na Pasta: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Alerta");
```

Ou simplificando e mantendo a generalidade:

```
public static string[] GetFiles(string sourceFolder, string filters, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption) {
   return filters.Split('|').SelectMany(filter =>
          System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, filter, searchOption)).ToArray();
}
```

Fonte: [resposta do Albert no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8466982/221800)

Embora não sei se é necessário fazer isto. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) indicando que o "xlsx" também é pego.

> When you use the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern such as "*.txt", the number of characters in the specified extension affects the search as follows:
>
> - If the specified extension is exactly three characters long, the method returns files with extensions that begin with the specified extension. For example, "*.xls" returns both "book.xls" and "book.xlsx".
> - In all other cases, the method returns files that exactly match the specified extension. For example, "*.ai" returns "file.ai" but not "file.aif".
>   When you use the question mark wildcard character, this method returns only files that match the specified file extension. For example, given two files, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", in a directory, a search pattern of "file?.txt" returns just the first file, whereas a search pattern of "file*.txt" returns both files.

Como há este comportamento não sei se qualquer solução é ideal a não ser fazer a loucura de criar um sistema próprio de captação dos arquivos e um filtro na com os próprios critérios. Dificilmente vale o esforço. Então acho que a segunda solução usando o LINQ acaba sendo a melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/CountFiles.cs)

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando Linq to Objects

**1 - Forma**

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
int length = files.Where(x => x.ToLower().EndsWith(".xls") || x.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx")).Count();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Arquivos na Pasta: " + length.ToString(), "Alerta");
```

---

**2 - Forma**

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
int length = files
                .Where(x => x.ToLower().Substring(x.Length - 4).Equals(".xls") || x.ToLower().Substring(x.Length - 5).Equals(".xlsx"))
                .Count();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Arquivos na Pasta: " + length.ToString(), "Alerta");
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava. Usei a forma 2 para resolver.

Comment: @LeandroDíaz isso ai ... vlw