# Como ler arquivos de pasta e subpasta?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

Eu tenho uma função pra ler os arquivos da pasta, e não está funcionando. 
preciso de uma função funcional que leia os arquivos das pastas e das subpastas. 
Segue o código:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
            txtArquivo.Text = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString();

            //Marca o diretório a ser listado
            DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(txtArquivo.Text);
            //Executa função GetFile(Lista os arquivos desejados de acordo com o parametro)
            FileInfo[] Arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles("*.xml; *xlsx;");

            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
```

Comment: Você usou `diretorio.GetFiles("*.xml; *xlsx;");`. Esta forma de usar mais um padrão de busca não está documentado e nos teste que eu fiz, não foi possível pegar os dados das duas extensões, pelo contrário, usando os dois padrões separados com `;` faz retornar nada.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 12):

Se você estiver usando pelo menos o .NET 4.0 basicamente você precisa disto:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

Ou pode usar desde a versão 2.0:

```
Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/AllDirs.cs).

Ou seja, o que você precisava conhecer é a sobrecarga com o parâmetro de [searchOptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1).

Se quiser pegar uma extensão, específica é só mudar o padrão de busca de `"*.*"` para o extensão que deseja. Se quiser pegar mais de uma extensão terá que usar a solução que já lhe indiquei na minha [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30800/101).

Existe um [exemplo completo da Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303974/how-to-recursively-search-directories-by-using-visual-c?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) usando outra abordagem.